# How to pin open a sideNav in Angular-Material Design

Tags: angularjs, material-design, ecmascript-6, angular-material

I have ben using

```
<md-sidenav md-component-id="leftNav" md-is-open="vm.isOpen"
            md-is-locked-open="vm.isPinned" ... >
    <i class="fa fa-bars float-right" ng-click="vm.toggleNav()"></i>
    ...
</md-sidenav>
```

with the toggleNave method in the controller setting the value

```
class MyController {
    constructor($mdSideNav) {
        this.mdSideNav = mdSideNav;
        this.isPinned = false;
        this.isOpen = false;
    }

    toggleNav = (navId) => {
        this.$mdSideNav(navId).toggle().then( () => {
            this.isPinned = this.isOpen;
        }
    }
}
```

But this causes the screen to flash on open and close, and it does not seem to be the best way to pin open a sideNav.

The desire is to have the nave toggle open/closed but to stay sticky open until I close it.

If I use md-is-locked="$media('')" then the sideNav locks open and never closes until the window shrinks below media-size.  This is not what I want.

If I do not use md-is-locked at all, then the sideNav collapses shut when you click away from it, but I want it to stay open! until I want to close it.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

BTW: I am using ES6, hence the class and arrow functions. :-)

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the documentation, I don't think you need to use the isPinned and isOpen variables as it looks like the toggle function handles it.

Hence, this

```
toggleNav = (navId) => {
    this.$mdSideNav(navId).toggle().then( () => {
        this.isPinned = this.isOpen;
    }
}
```

Would be come

```
toggleNav = (navId) => {
    this.$mdSideNav(navId).toggle();
}
```

To make this work you will need to pass through the id of the sideNav

So this

```
<i class="fa fa-bars float-right" ng-click="vm.toggleNav()"></i>
```

Would become

```
<i class="fa fa-bars float-right" ng-click="vm.toggleNav('leftNav')"></i>
```

Finally, worth checking the version of Material Design you are using, there seems to be quite a few issues when not using the >0.8 version.

See the example for right nav in the docs [Side Nav Material Design](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.sidenav)

Comment: Notice how the toggle will open the side nav, but only temporarily. Click/tap anywhere else in the middle pane and the side nav closes automatically. If you wanted to toggle it to stay open, then you need something a bit more than just the toggle.

Comment: Right. [Check this out](http://codepen.io/markwcollins/pen/KwrgOE) I just defined a boolean $scope.keepOpen and mapped it to 'md-is-locked-open'. I think by just changing this you should get the desired result. Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately using a boolean is not a very good solution. For instance, you cannot then close the sidenav by clicking outside it anymore.
I have the same problem as @KendrickBurson. The strange thing is that the demo site for material design works without boolean. I have tried to imitate that code without success.

Comment: You're right. To get it to work as the material design demo, you don't need a boolean. Using `toggle()` will work just fine. However, I thought that @KendrickBurson wanted it to stay open; hence the using of the boolean.